# What is an object of Type T supposed to mean?

Tags: .net, json

What is an object of Type T supposed to mean?

I just cannot seem to understand this.. parsing a JSON string to an Array would have been the easiest thing in the world in vbscript.. why is it so much more complicated in .NET?

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
//List<string> listJSON = new List<string>();

//IList<KeyValue> jList = js.Deserialize<IList<KeyValue>>(strJSON);
//List<KeyValue> persons = new JavaScriptSerializer()
//    .Deserialize<List<KeyValue>>(strJSON);
//Console.WriteLine(persons.Count);

Array arrJSON = js.Deserialize<KeyValue[]>(strJSON);

public class KeyValue
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
}
```

The error is: No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'WCFPull.KeyValue[]'.

Not getting the array populate yet
Updated Code:

```
namespace LoLSummoner
{
    public class KeyValue
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public string name {get; set;}
        public int profileIconId {get; set;}
        public int summonerLevel {get; set;}
        public int revisionDate {get; set;}
    }
}
namespace LoLSummoner
{
    public class Summoner : ISummoner
    {

        public int GetSummonerID(string SummonerName)
        {
            int summonerId = 0;

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string strJSON = client.DownloadString("http://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.2/summoner/by-name/" + SummonerName + "?api_key=xxx");

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            KeyValue[] arrJSON = js.Deserialize<List<KeyValue>>(strJSON).ToArray();

            return summonerId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `T` is a Generic Type Parameter. See [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is a Generic Type Parameter. See [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

> Generics introduce to the .NET Framework the concept of type parameters, which make it possible to design classes and methods that defer the specification of one or more types until the class or method is declared and instantiated by client code.
>
> .. *by using a generic type parameter T you can write a single class that other client code can use without incurring the cost or risk of runtime casts* or boxing operations ..

(In this case, JavaScriptSerializer also *uses* the type information to determine how to parse the JSON into the resulting objects - here it instructs the serializer to parse the JSON Array as List *of* a certain type.)

The code fails because there is a [Constraint on T](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), namely: `T : new()`:

> With `T : new()`, the type argument *must* have a public parameterless constructor [so that a new instance of type T can be trivially created].

(But *no array type can be pass this constraint*; if they did, then the best result would be the ability to create an *empty* array, as arrays have a fixed size.)

---

To deserialize the JSON, use the `List<T>` type (note the use of a *concrete type*) as originally presented:

```
IList<KeyValue> arrJSON = js.Deserialize<List<KeyValue>>(strJSON);
```

(Using `IList<KeyValue>` for `T` won't work because it is an interface which cannot be instantiated and fails the `T : new()` the constraint. However, `List<T>` implements `IList<T>` which is why the variable can be declared to use the interface.)

Or save some typing with [`var` and type inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx):

```
var arrJSON = js.Deserialize<List<KeyValue>>(strJSON);
```

(The `arrJSON` variable is implicitly inferred to have a type of `List<KeyValue>`.)

Or really get back an `KeyValue[]` using the [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx) Enumerable extension method:

```
KeyValue[] arrJSON = js.Deserialize<List<KeyValue>>(strJSON).ToArray();
```

(It will still be initially deserialized into a List, and *I* would generally keep it as a List/Enumerable.)

Comment: thanks! That makes sense. Been working with it a while but my array wont populate. The JSON string is definitely there when I debug.

Comment: @JoJo Create a new question - focusing on the exact issue (basically, this should be whatever issue the original question title summarizes). Include the *actual* JSON text downloaded (as reported by the VS debugger), as well, and any new (but hopefully different) exception messages, if any. Also, you return `summonerId`, but don't actually assign it a useful value!

Comment: I asked a new question but it did not get an answer I can understand how to resolve. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

type T are Generics - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Among other things, it allows the client to specify the object type upon instantiation.